# DBIx:Class many-to-many relationship with additional attribute

Tags: perl, many-to-many, catalyst, dbix-class

I'm working with DBIx::Class in Catalyst framework. My local goal is to add a new many-to-many relationship between users and, let's say, tasks. But there's one little trick I need. User can have different roles in task (like 'worker' or 'spectator').

So I have **users** table with these fields:

- id
- name

I have **task** table with these fields:

- id
- title
- description

And I have relationship table **user_tasks** with these fields:

- user_id
- task_id
- role

I have set up has_many from **users** to **user_tasks**, has_many from **tasks** to **user_tasks** and corresponding many_to_many relationships between **users** and **tasks**. And that plain part works as it should.

Then, for example, I want to get my user list including user's role in task identified by $task_id:

```
my $users = $schema->resultset('User')->with_task_role($task_id);
while (my $u = $users->next) {
    print "User: " . $u->name . ", role: " . $u->get_column('task_role');
}
```

So how should I code this **with_task_role** custom resultset to get this additional field with user's task role in my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all many-to-many is not a relationship. It's a accessor (a relationship bridge).

Second, the DBIx::Class has an excellent documentation. Take a look at join/prefetch.
In your ResultSet/User.pm file you should have something like:

```
sub with_task_role {
    my ($self, $task_id) = @_;

    return $self->search({
            'task.task_id' => $task_id,
        },
        {
            join     => { 'user_task' => 'task' },
            prefetch => { 'user_task' => 'task' },
        },
    );
}
```

PS:  Sorry, I didn't see that Ashley already answered
PS2: Before the last line "})" should be ")" only (fixed it)

Comment: I already know that DBIx::Class has an excellent documentation because I looked there first. And I've already tried this code above, but it can't get **user_tasks.role** field from this query!

Comment: Hmm. I beg my pardon. This code does work, that was my implementation of it which didn't (I used join OR prefetch, not together).

Comment: Good to hear it's working, it should work without prefetch also (only with join), but then you'll hit the database everytime you use any column from user_tasks or task.

Comment: One more thing: this join filters out empty connection and I'd prefer to have undef value instead. I.e. users are listed even if they don't have any role in the task.

Comment: See join_type in the docs: http://search.cpan.org/~frew/DBIx-Class-0.08192/lib/DBIx/Class/Relationship.pm If you have any additional questions, it would be better if you ask at the irc channel (irc.perl.org #dbix-class) you'll get much more help over there

Answer (score 2):

This is some `User` resultset code, unchanged, from the XUL (which is
no longer supported by any browsers) slideshow of the [DBIC
master class](http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/catalyst/-talks/yapc-na-2008/dbix-masterclass.xul) (.xul resource). I highly recommend downloading the slides, which read fine as plain text, to review. They were a great eye-opener for resultsets for me.

You'll have to adjust the result source names to match your own but
this should be what you want and a bit more flexible to boot with the
`_role_to_id` which allows you to pass role objects or ids.

```
  sub with_role {
    my ($self, $role) = @_;
    $self->search({
        'role_links.role_id' => $role->id
      },
      { join => 'role_links' }
    );
  }

  sub _role_to_id {
    my ($self, $role) = @_;
    return blessed($role) ? $role->id : $role;
  }

  sub with_any_role {
    my ($self, @roles) = @_;
    $self->search({
        'role_links.role_id' => {
          -in => [
            map { $self->_role_to_id($_) } @roles
          ]
        }
      },
      { join => 'role_links' }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful for my further work in this direction, but doesn't resolve questioned issue to add role column to existing resultset without filtering out roles.