# dbix::class many-to-many with additional parameters as a JSON

Tags: perl, many-to-many, dbix-class

I have a many-to-many relationship in `DBIx::Class` similar to [DBIx:Class many-to-many relationship with additional attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112471/dbixclass-many-to-many-relationship-with-additional-attribute/6113179#6113179).  Consider that same example on the `user_task` table with a `params` column which is type text.

I've been using JSON strings in table columns and doing the inflate/deflate as in

```
__PACKAGE__->inflate_column(
    'params',
    {   inflate => sub {
            decode_json shift;
        },
        deflate => sub {
            encode_json shift;
        }
    }
);
```

The result

```
use Data::Dump qw/dd/; 
my $user_task = $schema->resultset("UserTask")->find({userid=>1,taskid=>1});

dd {$user_task->get_columns};
```

results in

```
{userid=>1,taskid=>1,role=>"admin",params=>"{}"}
```

however if

```
dd {$user_task->get_inflated_columns};
```

I don't get the expected result.  It appears that all of the columns are inflating. From the documentation https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Row#get_inflated_columns, it seems that it should only inflated those columns which have a `inflate_column` for.

This also appears to be only on many-to-many bridge tables in that if I call `get_inflated_columns` on non-many-to-many results that the expected occurs.

**Question**

Is this a bug (or feature)?  If it is a feature, is there a reason this doesn't work?

Alternatively, I can build up a result by selectively calling `get_inflated_column` on only the `params` column.  This seems like it should be unnecessary but perhaps a reasonable work around.

Comment: What restult do you get when you call get_inflated_columns?

Comment: It seems to inflate the `params` field fine, but the `userid` is a object of type `MyApp::Schema::Result::User`

Comment: Because you‘ve defined a relationship with the same name as the foreign key column. In my schemas I use a different name, in your case I‘d name it ‚user‘.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated above, the details were in the `many_to_many` call, where I had `userid` as the third argument see [the documentation for many_to_many](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship#many_to_many).  It should be the name of the accessor.